Is every $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable space also ultrametrizable?
Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a metric space such that $d$ has range contained in the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$.
Question: is it true that $X$ is ultrametrizable?

Additional info (edited 30/12/2024):
This question is about topological spaces and their properties, not about any of the additional structures they inherit from being metrizable or ultrametrizable. In this sense, $X$ is just a topological space that happens by chance to be metrizable with a metric having values in $\mathbb{Q}$, and the goal is to understand the consequences of this on its topology.
We say that the topological space $X$ is ultrametrizable if it satisfies one of the following equivalent conditions:

It admits (another) ultrametric that induces the same topology of $d$.
$\mathrm{dim}(X)=0$, i.e. every open cover can be refined into a clopen partition.
$\mathrm{Ind}(X)=0$, i.e. every pair of closed sets can be separated by a clopen set.
It is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\lambda^\omega$ for some cardinal $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ has the discrete topology and $\lambda^\omega$ has the product topology.

(Theorem 7.3.2 and Exercise 7.3.F of [1])
It is easy to show that $X$ satisfy $\mathrm{ind}(X)=0$, i.e. it has a basis of clopen sets.
If $X$ is separable, we have $\mathrm{ind}(X)=\mathrm{dim}(X)=\mathrm{Ind}(X)$ (Theorem 7.3.3 of [1]), thus for separable spaces the answer is yes.
References:
[1] Engelking's book "general topology", 1989

Would you be more explicit: is the answer "yes" if $X$ is separable?

I am not quite sure whether it is reasonable for ultrametrizability to only demand that another ultrametric induces the same topology in place of the same uniformity. There is a notion of uniform spaces being non-archimedean.

@YCor I think every separable metric space with a basis of clopen sets admits a topological embedding into Cantor space.

@Z.M I think that version of the question has a relatively easy negative answer with $\mathbb{Q}$ as a metric space, since a uniformly equivalent metric would need to extend to a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Every reasonable definition of "ultrametrisable" should IMO agree with being a subspace (in Top, or in uniform category) of countable limit of discrete spaces; and ultra-uniform-able should correspond to subspaces of arbitrary prodiscrete objects.

Yes sorry, all questions make sense but for this question, I'm only interested in topological spaces and their properties. The additional structures (metrics or ultrametrics) are only useful for me for the consequences they have on the topology. Probably I should have written "Let $(X,\tau)$ be a metrizable topological space having a compatible metric $d$ such that..." to make things clearer.

@DenisT Yes, that is still equivalent: a topological space is ultrametrizable if and only if it is homeomorphic (as a topological space) to a subspace of $\lambda^\omega$ for some cardinal $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is treated as a topological space with the discrete topology and $\lambda^\omega$ has the product topology (=Tychonoff topology).

@YCor Yes, for separable spaces being $\mathbb{Q}$-metrizable is equivalent to being ultrametrizable. One way to see this is as James E Hanson explained (thanks!). There is also an explicit reference in Theorem 7.3.3 of Engelking's book "general topology", 1989.

Edited the question to take care of all suggestions.

Thanks. By the way, could the question be asked with $\mathbf{Q}$ replaced by any subset $D$ of the nonnegative reals with dense complement? or even, just assuming that the complement of $D$ accumulates at zero? This is enough to have a basis of open subsets.

Yes, I agree: replacing $\mathbb{Q}$ with any subsets $D\subset [0,\infty)$ such that for all $\varepsilon\in \mathbb{R}^+$ there is $\delta\in \mathbb{R}^+$, $\delta<\varepsilon$ such that $\delta\notin D$, we still get $\mathrm{ind}(X)=0$. The question itself also makes sense for any $D$ of this form, but I have no idea if the answer is the same for all $D$ (so I asked it for $\mathbb{Q}$ since it seemed the most natural choice for a first question).

Cant you just round up? Let us try to define a metric on the real numbers. Take the usual metric and cut after say 4 nonzero decimal places. So for example the new distance between two real numbers with usual distance 0.0000123456 would be 0.00001235. Does this construction define a $\mathbb{Q}$-valued metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

@HenrikRüping Rounding is discontinuous. There cannot be a $\mathbb{Q}$-valued metric on any connected space, in particular this doesn't work on $\mathbb{R}$.

@HenrikRüping If you have a $\mathbf{Q}$-valued metric on a metric space and $r_n$ is a sequence of positive irrationals tending to zero, then balls of radius in ${r_n:n\ge 0}$ are clopen and form a basis of the topology.
